# PyMySQL not not storing data as expected

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pymssql

I am using BeautifulSoup to retrieve some data from a website. Then I am using PyMySQL to store that data in MySQL. However, I am getting the following error:
    TypeError: execute( ) takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 7 were given

This error is pointing to the "cur.execute" command.

Here is my code:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock',
                   user='root', passwd='---', db='mysql', 
charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('USE HuntsPointsBusinesses')

def store (name, rating, phone, address, link):
    #The error is pointing to the following line:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO HuntsPointYelp (name, rating, phone, address, 
link) VALUES ("%s", "%s","%s", "%s","%s")', 
                name, rating, phone, address, link)
    cur.connection.commit() 

def getInformation(bs): 


    listLinks = [] 
    restGrid = bs.find_all ("ul", {"class": "lemon--ul__373c0__1_cxs 
undefined list__373c0__2G8oH"}) 
    for i in restGrid: 

        link = i.find_all("a", {"href": re.compile ("/biz/.*")}) 
        for l in link: 

            if "target" in l.attrs and "name" in l.attrs and "rel" in 
l.attrs: 
                listLinks.append (l.attrs["href"])
    linksList = []           
    for link in listLinks[0::3]:

        newLink = ("https://www.yelp.com"+str(link))
        linksList.append (newLink)



    addressDiv = bs.find_all("div", {"class": re.compile 
(".*container__373c0__19wDx u-padding-l2.*text-align--
```

right__373c0__1cJDF")})

```
    addressTag = [a.find("span", {"class": re.compile("lemon-- 
span__373c0__3997G")}) for a in addressDiv] 
    addressList = [addr.text for addr in addressTag] 




    phoneDiv = bs.find_all("div", {"class": re.compile 
(".*container__373c0__19wDx u-padding-l2.*text-align-- 
 right__373c0__1cJDF")}) 

    phones_ = [p.find("p") for p in phoneDiv] 

    phonesList = [ph.text for ph in phones_] 




    ratingDiv = bs.find_all ("div", {"class": re.compile ("lemon-- 
div.*hidden__373c0__8Jq2I")}) 
    ratingsList = [] 
    for r in ratingDiv: 
        if "aria-label" in r.attrs: 

            if r.attrs is not None:
                ratingsList.append (r["aria-label"]) 


    restGrid = bs.find_all ("ul", {"class": "lemon--ul__373c0__1_cxs 
undefined list__373c0__2G8oH"}) 
    namesList = [] 
    for i in restGrid: 
        h3 = i.find_all ("h3") 
        for h in h3:

            target = h.find_all ("a") 
            for t in target: 
                if "name" in t.attrs: 

                    if t.attrs is not None: 
                        namesList.append (t["name"]) 

    store (namesList, ratingsList, phonesList, addressList, linksList)


html_page = requests.get("https://www.yelp.com/search? 
cflt=restaurants&find_loc=Hunts+Point%2C+Bronx%2C+NY+10474")

soup = BeautifulSoup (html_page.text, "html.parser")

TypeError: execute( ) takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 7 were 
given
```

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually do not need to surround your %s with quotes, as the module tokenizes this and handles this for you:

```
def store (name, rating, phone, address, link):
    #The error is pointing to the following line:
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO HuntsPointYelp (name, rating, phone, address, 
link) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', 
                name, rating, phone, address, link)
    cur.connection.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding, but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Then try calling that function directly manually giving it variables.  If this works, than one of your variables is coming in as a list.

Comment: Got it. So in this case I can't use lists to store the values in the data base? I will try that out

Comment: You can, but you have to convert them into a database friendly object.  For instance I use postgres, so I can store json values directly into the database, so I convert my list into json and then save.